# AWS static website for desktop and mobile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, mobile-website, mobile-browser

I have a static website hosted on AWS S3 and server with CloudFront. Does it possible to server different versions or different S3 buckets depending on whether request from mobile or desktop browser?

Answer (score 0):

No. Amazon S3 simply serves static content with no "back-end" logic.

Any changes you would like to make for mobile/desktop will need to be done *within* the content that is being served. For example, using **responsive design** in JavaScript and CSS so that the same page appears different based upon the client and window size.